# JPA & Flyway boolean type in Oracle

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, flyway

I use Flyway and Spring JPA for creating tables and persistence. The approach below works well for H2 embedded database (set in oracle compatibility mode). But I noticed it creates the boolean field still as a "boolean" in database, which is not supported in Oracle.

So my question is is this still going to work when I start using a real Oracle database? that flyway will detect the database type and before creation map the boolean to a Number(1) or so?

In the *flyway* script:

```
Create table Account{
    ...
    USER_EXISTS BOOLEAN not null,
    ....
}
```

And in the *Account Entity* class:

```
    private Boolean usertExists = true;
```

Comment: What prevents you from trying an Oracle db? XE is free and it supports enough features to be a valid database for development and some testing...

Comment: @ Boris Pavlović Obviously there are some reasons, which are irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Flyway placeholder for the datatype and set the value to `BOOLEAN` for the H2 environments and `Number(1)` for the Oracle ones.

`Create table Account{
    ...
    USER_EXISTS ${boolean_datatype} not null,
    ....
}`

Comment: tnx, So this means my approach is NOT gonna work as it is on Oracle right now? Btw ${boolean_datatype} will be in my spring-boot configuration?

Comment: You will need to set the different values for `flyway.placeholders.boolean_datatype` in your various Spring Boot profiles.